# How does DDMS get Native Heap Data?

Tags: android, ddms, android-testing, android-debug, adb

Does DDMS use `dumheap -n <PID> <file>` command internally to get the native heap data or does it use any other mechanism? Please can you point me the line in code where this is happening.